# Testing Multicollinearity with R (vif)

Tags: r

I have a data set (example below) and I want to regress with multiply regressors. When I want to test the multicollinearity with `vif()` I get the Error saying:

> Error in UseMethod("vcov") :
> inapplicable method for 'vcov' applied  to object of class "data.frame".   Additional: Warning message: Unknown or uninitialised
> column: `coefficients`.

-->The Error is translated

My code is the following:

```
subset_cor <- subset(Relevante_V03, 
                     select=c(xsga, xrd, at, sale, intr, inflr, 
                               sale_py, at_py, sale_py_at_py, value, dt,
                                re, txt, p_con, marketingspending, R_at_py))
    
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
lm01 <- Relevante_V03 %>% 
  mutate(sic = factor(sic)) %>% 
  group_by(sic) %>% 
  filter(n() >= 10) %>% 
  group_split() %>% 
  map_dfr(.f = function(df){
    lm(marketingspending ~ intr + sale_py_at_py + R_at_py, data=df) %>% 
      glance() %>% 
      add_column(sic = unique(df$sic), .before = 1)
  }) 

library(car)
#paris(Relevante_V03, lower.panel=panel.smooth, cex = .8, pch = 21,
       bg="steelblue", diag.panel=panel.hist, cex.labels = 1.2, font.labels=2,
        upper.panel=panel.cor)
vif(lm01)
```

(Also it does not let me do the `Paris()` function part. Is there an other option to give me data to that?)

My Data set looks something like this:

| Name | Segment | Sale | Year | Asset | Another header |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3401 | 10000 | 2000 | 200000 | x |
| A | 3401 | 20000 | 2001 | 250000 | x |
| B | 2201 | 15000 | 2004 | 280000 | x |
| B | 2201 | 23000 | 2009 | 320000 | x |
| B | 2201 | 28000 | 2010 | 390000 | x |
| C | 2201 | 30000 | 2000 | 210000 | x |
| C | 2201 | 18000 | 2004 | 200000 | x |
| D | 1 | 28000 | 2000 | 400000 | x |
| D | 1 | 38000 | 2001 | 521000 | x |

How can I fix this problem?

I want to extend the lm() regression afterwards with more variables do I have to consider something for that? (for example is a character variable okay?)

Edit:

Based on the help in the comments I changed my approach to the following code (errors will be mentioned in code after the code it appeard):

```
install.packages(c("funModeling","gvlma", "caret"))
install.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("broom")
library(ggplot2)
library(funModeling)
library(gvlma)
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

table_lm01 <- df_status(Relevante_V03) #ganz am Anfang sinnvoller?

#splitting data
mpg <- Relevante_V03 %>% 
  mutate(fdyear = factor(fdyear),
         sic = factor(sic)) %>% 
  group_by(fdyear, sic) %>% 
  filter(n() >= 10) %>% 
  group_split()

# set the seed for repeatability
set.seed(59385)


# create training vector of indices for each group for training the model
tr <- mpg %>% 
  map(~ createDataPartition(.x$marketingspending, 
                            list = F, 
                            p = .7))


# now map over mpg groups and tr vectors
lm01 <- map(1:98, ~lm(marketingspending ~ intr + sale_py_at_py + R_at_py + dt
                      + p_con + intr,  data = mpg[[.x]][tr[[.x]],]))
                     
                       
                       
                       


resMod <- map_dfr(lm01, glance) %>% 
  add_column(ySic = map_chr(mpg, ~paste(unique(.x$fdyear), 
                                        unique(.x$sic), 
                                        sep = ".")),
             .before = 1)


#testing lm 
testLM <- map(1:98,
              ~predict(lm01[[.x]], mpg[[.x]][-tr[[.x]], ]))
```

> #Error: There were 50 or more warnings (display the first 50 with
> warnings())

> ->50: In predict.lm(lm01[[.x]], mpg[[.x]][-tr[[.x]], ]) :   prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading

```
resPred <- map_dfr(1:98,
                   ~postResample(testLM[[.x]], 
                                 mpg[[.x]][-tr[[.x]], ]$marketingspending))

resMod <- map_dfr(lm01, glance) %>% 
  add_column(yCyl = map_chr(mpg, ~paste(unique(.x$fdyear), 
                                        unique(.x$sic), 
                                        sep = ".")),
             .before = 1)

View(resMod)

#tsSigma <- map(1:98, ~sqrt(sum((mpg[[.x]][-tr[[.x]], ]$marketingspending - 
#                                   testLM[[.x]])^2)/lm01[[.x]]$df.residual))

V#iew(tsSigma)

#testing assumption that regression is a "good" regression

map(lm01, summary)


cbind01 <- cbind(resMod[, 1:3], resPred) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(fit = ifelse(r.squared > Rsquared, 
                      "Check for overfit",
                      "Overfit unlikely"))

#cbind01$fit %>% summarise_all( ~ sum(is.na(x)))
#table(cbind01$fit)

install.packages(c("car"))
library(car)
vif.lm <- Relevante_V03 %>% 
  mutate(sic = factor(sic)) %>% 
  group_by(sic, fdyear) %>% 
  filter(n() >= 10) %>% 
  group_split() %>% 
  map_dfr(.f = function(df){
    lm(marketingspending ~ intr + sale_py_at_py + R_at_py + txt + value + dt, data=Relevante_V03) %>% 
      vif()
  })
```

| ySic | r.squared | adj.r.squared | RMSE | Rsquared | MAE | fit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000.2832 | 0.3059 | 0.0535 | 19162165 | 0.6041 | 182... | O u |
| 2001.3674 | 0.4932 | 0.2035 | 3479144 | 0.9801 | 270... | O u |
| 2001.3826 | 0.4932 | 0.2035 | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 2003.3954 | 0.9356 | 0.8718 | 7460919 | 0.0001 | 480... | Cfo |

O u= Overfit unlikely
Cfo = Check for overfit

Furthermore in the result of the "cbind" I get a table for 98 lines and some have the result NA (how is that possible?) and some "check for overfitting" and some "overfit unlikely". Question to that how can I get the exact number of the 3 options in that column? And when do I have to say that it is overfitting or when not? Is it a percentage or anything else?

Thanks to @Kat for helping me getting this far :)

Comment: use `vif` on the model object, eg, `vif(lm(...))`, not data frames

Comment: ah okay. I tried it but it gave me again an error (see edit section)

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy with the structure in which you created our `lm()` output, just do the same with the `vif()` output. You can't use the model when there is there no model. Your output is just metrics. Metrics won't work for finding the `vif`. Copy the code, but instead of `glance`, `vif`.

```
vif.lm <- Relevante_V03 %>% 
  mutate(sic = factor(sic)) %>% 
  group_by(sic) %>% 
  filter(n() >= 10) %>% 
  group_split() %>% 
  map_dfr(.f = function(df){
    lm(marketingspending ~ intr + sale_py_at_py + R_at_py, data=df) %>% 
      vif()
  })
```

---

---

Based on your comment, I thought I would provide more information regarding the assumptions and testing the model.

For this, I grabbed some readily available data in R. I used `mpg` from the `ggplot2` package.

```
library(funModeling) # just for df_status
                     # ran before tidyverse, so dplyr has precedence
library(gvlma)       # used for assumptions of MLR
library(caret)       # used for partitioning and prediction metrics
library(tidyverse)   # from your original code
library(broom)       # from your original code

# inspecting the data
str(mpg)
df_status(mpg)
```

Next, I split the data into groups, as you did, but without running the model.

```
# splitting the data
mpg <- mpg %>% 
  mutate(year = factor(year),
         cyl = factor(cyl)) %>% 
  group_by(year, cyl) %>% 
  filter(n() >= 10) %>% 
  group_split()
```

Now I will partition the data so that the models can first be trained then tested. I will also use the model to assess the assumptions of this type of regression.

```
# set the seed for repeatability
set.seed(59385)
# create training vector of indices for each group for training the model
tr <- mpg %>% 
  map(~ createDataPartition(.x$displ, 
                            list = F, 
                            p = .7))
```

The models will be trained using the vectors of indices in `tr` (one for each group).

```
# now map over mpg groups and tr vectors
lm01 <- map(1:6, ~lm(displ ~ cty + hwy, data = mpg[[.x]][tr[[.x]],]))
```

The tidy setup for the results can still be obtained, just like your original work.

```
resMod <- map_dfr(lm01, glance) %>% 
  add_column(yCyl = map_chr(mpg, ~paste(unique(.x$year), 
                                        unique(.x$cyl), 
                                        sep = ".")),
             .before = 1)
```

There are a lot of ways to test the assumptions. One of the more thorough methods I have found is from the package `gvlma`.

```
map(lm01, gvlma)
```

For this data, only the first model did not meet the assumptions:

```
# [[1]]
# 
# Call:
# lm(formula = displ ~ cty + hwy, data = mpg[[.x]][tr[[.x]], ])
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)          cty          hwy  
#     3.35394      0.02865     -0.06536  
# 
# 
# ASSESSMENT OF THE LINEAR MODEL ASSUMPTIONS
# USING THE GLOBAL TEST ON 4 DEGREES-OF-FREEDOM:
# Level of Significance =  0.05 
# 
# Call:
#  .f(x = .x[[i]]) 
# 
#                       Value   p-value                   Decision
# Global Stat        13.80206 0.0079543 Assumptions NOT satisfied!
# Skewness            0.07551 0.7834808    Assumptions acceptable.
# Kurtosis            1.46654 0.2258932    Assumptions acceptable.
# Link Function      11.77835 0.0005992 Assumptions NOT satisfied!
# Heteroscedasticity  0.48167 0.4876676    Assumptions acceptable.
```

You can test the models by first predicting with the test data, then getting the metrics for the predictions versus actuals with `postResample` from the `caret` package.

```
# now for testing the models
testLM <- map(1:6,
              ~predict(lm01[[.x]], mpg[[.x]][-tr[[.x]], ]))

# find the results
resPred <- map_dfr(1:6,
               ~postResample(testLM[[.x]], 
                             mpg[[.x]][-tr[[.x]], ]$displ))
# # A tibble: 6 × 3
#    RMSE Rsquared   MAE
#   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 0.282    0.211 0.256
# 2 0.430    0.235 0.374
# 3 0.836    0.175 0.635
# 4 0.210    0.497 0.186
# 5 0.293    0.266 0.265
# 6 0.474    0.163 0.434
```

To make it easier to recognize if there is a problem, I compared the training and testing like this:

```
cbind(resMod[, 1:3], resPred) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(fit = ifelse(r.squared > Rsquared, 
                      "Check for overfit",
                      "Overfit unlikely"))
#     yCyl r.squared adj.r.squared      RMSE  Rsquared       MAE               fit
# 1 1999.4 0.4506805    0.41405924 0.2821392 0.2106108 0.2556183 Check for overfit
# 2 1999.6 0.5367920    0.50591147 0.4299883 0.2345990 0.3738415 Check for overfit
# 3 1999.8 0.1447143    0.04409243 0.8357696 0.1750658 0.6354507  Overfit unlikely
# 4 2008.4 0.2857471    0.22363818 0.2095897 0.4969283 0.1861229  Overfit unlikely
# 5 2008.6 0.1041972    0.02630127 0.2929450 0.2656493 0.2645665  Overfit unlikely
# 6 2008.8 0.1266099    0.06422494 0.4743184 0.1628117 0.4343889  Overfit unlikely
```

In this example, the first two models are questionable, at best. The first model did not meet the assumptions; that is probably why there is so much volatility between training and testing. The second model must be interesting...

Comment: Ah okay perfect thank you very much. Just one last question I added in the lm() function in the group_by( sic, fdyear) and it lets me do it in the regression but not in the vif() function. Do you now why? (Error code says: there are aliased coefficients in the model). Also it sounds like you would do the function in an other way may I ask how?

Comment: In this case, the `vif()` error is likely telling you that you have a near-perfect or perfect correlation between two or more variables in your model. As for how I would assemble the model, you have a creative and excellent bit of code. However, the model is gone. Linear regression validity is based on multiple assumptions that your data must meet for the results to be valid. Additionally, it can suffer from over-fitting. The easiest method to test the assumptions is with the model. The best way to test for model fit is through training and testing it.

Comment: wow thank you very much for your effort. I have to ask why do we train/test the model? Because what would it mean if the model is not fitting? Is it the same as the vif?

Comment: [I think that source should give you some insight](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat462/node/185/).

Comment: Ah okay I See so we are testing to understand if we are using to many or to less variables. I am still not quite sure where the difference between vif and testing is but I have other questions: the first is simple basic I can't find gvlma and funModeling in r? I am using a Mac but that should not make a difference or? And second if I try to do the part with resMod <- map.... it tells me that the column have to be identical. Is it possible to discuss this in a chat here? because with the limit of characters to wright I can't copy my changes to the code you send

Comment: Found my issue with the second problem (think so) I had to set for lm10 <- map(1:190... and not 1:6

Comment: We can talk more in chat - try this for the libraries (so you have the exact spelling and casing: `install.packages(c("funModeling","gvlma"))` . I realized that you pull `sigma` from the models, but I gathered `RMSE` for testing. If you would like to have the `sigma` for the prediction (testing), use this: `tsSigma <- map(1:6, ~sqrt(sum((mpg[[.x]][-tr[[.x]], ]$displ - testLM[[.x]])^2)/lm01[[.x]]$df.residual))`

Comment: Oh actually I don't know the difference between RMSE and sigma? It´s my first time doing a regression :/. My problem with my solution was that I did not get the coefficients from the lm() regression is it because of sigma? And the package thing seems to work but if I want to use map() I get an error: Lapack routine dgesv: Systeem is precies singulier: U[36,36] = 0

Comment: I think I have corrected all the errors. However, I still have NA's in the final result (table) and I don't understand why. I think it's because of the resPred part, which partially doesn't give me values for Rsquared. I just do not understand why?

Comment: Since you had trouble with the original model with `map(lm01, gvlma)`, try `map(lm01, summary)`. Which model or models have a problem? If the `lm` object is off somehow, nothing else will work right. If it's an option, you could include sample data so that this is reproducible (like the output from `dput(dataobject)` or  `dput(head(dataObject))` so that I can see exactly what you're working with.

Comment: I think it is because of the potential errors I am getting in the "testLM" section. When I display the errors here using the warnings() function, it says that "prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading". I suspect that this is because the interest rate (infler) is calculated on the basis of the fiscal year (for example 10.01.2000), which may result in identical values in the groups. And therefore resPred is wrong. Can this be true? I will edit the post so that it is recognizable which data set I get as a result. If you need more information, please let me know and I will post it.